# Concentric circle with random colors in JS canvas (with loop)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to draw concentric circles with javascript canvas with a loop. The circles have to be a random color each time they are drawn. I have tried to draw the circles with the code below but it didn't work. Thanks for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <script>
      var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      while ( i=50 ; i < 5; i=i-5 ) {

      context.beginPath();
      context.arc(300, 300, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      //context.fillStyle = 'green';
      //context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();

      }
//the code below worked for one circle 
      context.beginPath(); 
      context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
      context.fillStyle = 'green';
      context.fill();
      context.lineWidth = 5;
      context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
      context.stroke();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At first glance, the while loop conditions look wrong.  If you start with i being 50, how will it ever be less than 5?

Answer (score 2):

### Multiple Typos

Three typographical type errors for your consideration:

1. The `while` loop is a `for` loop. In

   ```
    while ( i=50 ; i < 5; i=i-5 )
   ```

   replace `while` with `for`
2. The loop condition is false, so the loop never executes after fixing 1.

   ```
   for( i=50; i < 5; i=i-5)
   ```

   replace `i < 5` with `i > 5`
3. The circles are off canvas and can't be seen. For demonstrations purposes only,  replace

   ```
    context.arc(300, 300, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ```

   with, say,

   ```
        context.arc(100, 100, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
   ```

   and remove, or fully comment out, the "working" code example to remove syntax errors.

A working example using a line width of 3px:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

for ( i=50 ; i > 5; i=i-5 ) {
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(100, 100, i, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    context.fillStyle = 'green';
    context.fill()
    context.lineWidth = 3;
    context.strokeStyle = '#003300';
    context.stroke();
}
```

```html
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```